# How do I defeat a yeti?

Tags: road-not-taken

There is a yeti in the forest! He is in my way. How can I defeat him? I tried just throwing stuff at him, but so far nothing has worked.

Comment: Read not taken? Do you mean "Road not taken"?

Comment: *runs to edit like a ninja*

Comment: As moderator you should delete that tag :)